# Bajar archivos por php y mysqli

Tags: php, html5, mysqli

Estoy intentando implementar un sistema para bajar un archivo desde un formulario html y php, que apuntan a una base de datos mysqli de mariadb 10

No tengo mucha idea de PHP. Mi intención es poder bajar los archivos de dos formas, una individualmente con la siguiente sentencia incluida en una tabla.

```
<td><a href="download.php?GetID=<?php echo $row['ticket_index']; ?>">Download</a></td>
```

Que apunta a un archivo download.php que expongo abajo, pero no me funciona por el siguiente error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::bind_param() in /volume1/web/recibos/pages/download.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /volume1/web/recibos/pages/download.php on line 8

Pero dudo que aún así funcione. He estado buscando código que me pudiese funcionar.

La segunda forma para bajar los archivos es bajar todo los archivos en un zip bajo el criterio de fechas del formulario:

```
 <input type="date" name="ticket_date_from" /> A: <input type="date" name="ticket_date_to" /><br><br>


<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])) {
    $ticket_date_from = $_POST['ticket_date_from'];
    $ticket_date_to = $_POST['ticket_date_to'];
    $quantity_from = $_POST['quantity_from'];
    $quantity_to = $_POST['quantity_to'];
    $field = $_POST['field'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $busqueda = $_POST['busqueda'];
    $seguros = $_POST['seguros'];

    #Seguros
            if ($seguros == "todos") {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM recibos WHERE type='seguro'";
                $search_result = filterTable($query);

            #Renta
            } elseif ($field == "renta"){
                $query = "SELECT * FROM recibos WHERE $field='1'";
                $search_result = filterTable($query);

            }elseif ($field == "fecha"){

                $query = "SELECT * FROM recibos WHERE ticket_date BETWEEN '$ticket_date_from' and '$ticket_date_to'";
                $search_result = filterTable($query);



        }else{
                $query  = "select * from recibos";
                $search_result = filterTable($query);
                $count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($search_result);

        }
 function filterTable($query){
     include ('connection.php');
     $filter_result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
     return $filter_result;
}


?>
```

El código php del archivo download.php que está fallando.

```
  <?php
include ('connection.php');
if (isset($_GET['GetID'])){

    $ticket_index = $_GET['GetID'];
    $query_file="Select * from recibos where ticket_index = '".$ticket_index."' ";
    $result_file = mysqli_query($conn,$query_file);
    $result_file->bind_param(1,$ticket_index);
    $result_file->execute();
    $row=$result_file->fetch_assoc();

        $image_dir=$row['image_dir'];
    //$data = $search_result->fetch();

        $file ='upload/'.$data['image_dir'];

    if(file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Disposition: '.$data['disposition'].'; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }

}


?>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: El problema es que ejecutas la consulta normalmente (no preparada) y, por tanto, no puedes enlazar parámetros. Para consultas preparadas, revisa el manual de PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Al final resultó más fácil de lo que supuse:

<a class="boton_eliminar" href="../upload/<?php echo $row['image_dir']; ?>" download >Download</a>